# Sklearn recommended cluster algorithms for Unsupervised Learning

Tags: scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

Slowly getting into the word of Sklearn, more specific unsupervised clustering algorithms.
I’m working on a project that flattens xml file into csv file, that part is done.

Now I want to implement any of sklearn method to detect anomalies on my data.

The csv file is in  a Dataframe format where there are some column with descriptions and others have values. These values might also be decimals values `55,2`

Which of the Sklearn algorithms are more suggested for anomaly detection using unsupervised learning ?

At the beginning I just want to try and find the anomalies for the numbers, if there is any number that doesn’t belong there.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, clustering algorithm and anomaly detection algorithm are not the same things.
In clustering, the goal is to assign each of you instances into a group (cluster), wherein each group you have similar instances.
In anomaly detection, the goal is to find instnaces that are not similar to any of the other instances.

Some clustering algorithms, for example [DB-SCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html), create an "anomaly cluster". This cluster has all the instances that don't belong in any other cluster. I would suggest to try and see if it solve your problem.

Almost all of the clustering algorithms expect vector of numbers as input. If you want to use string columns you can use methods like [One Hot Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to transform the string into a vector of numbers. There are many ways to do that, and you can find some sk-learn implementations [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing).

Comment: does DBscan support decimals with comma or I need to replace the comma with a dort like from ```55,4 ```  to ```55.4 ```

Comment: does '55,4' represent one number or two? DBscan works with numbers, so you will have to transform your strings to integers.

Comment: @mandi you need to replace the ',' to a '.' if you are working with floats and convert the values to float type, if not, you can always consider the 55,4 a category and do the one hot encoding as recommended in this same answer.

Comment: the value is only one number so an integer but I have read somewhere that these algorithms sometimes don't work if an integer has a comma instead of a dot and that is why the question came

Comment: @mandi That is true because in Python 55,4 is a string, where 55.4 is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

> Which of the Sklearn algorithms are more suggested for anomaly detection using 
>   unsupervised learning?

The most used algorithms are [these ones](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#overview-of-outlier-detection-methods) recommended by sklearn.

> At the beginning I just want to try and find the anomalies for the
>   numbers, if there is any number that doesn’t belong there.

As I see it, you can try a novelty detection approach, [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#novelty-detection) you have a basic explanation. In my experience [OneClassSVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html) is a reliable algorithm.

Comment: do you know any other examples that go deeper into anomaly detection using one of these methods ?

Comment: An example of One class SVM to enter a little bit more on novelty and why use it: https://towardsdatascience.com/outlier-detection-with-one-class-svms-5403a1a1878c And regarding isolation forest, see this github repo that contains extended isolation forest. It also explains isolation forest BEAUTIFULLY https://github.com/sahandha/eif

Comment: if I may ask what are the differences between SVM and  PCA.  Also the link to SVM shows a  ROC Curve which is really important to display how good your method is working on finding anomalies.

Comment: SVM and PCA are two different things, you should need to research each one. SVM is a classification algorithm and PCA is an analytic "method" (which has a lot of uses). The link of SVM contains evaluation metrics like ROC curve (it's important, I agree), but in my opinion, the entire evaluation process is also important.